# How to fix ERROR TypeError: Class constructor HammerGestureConfig cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: angular, typescript, hammer.js

I have a problem when I add the ngx-gallery. 
When inspect an error appears
**ERROR Type Error: The class constructor HammerGestureConfig cannot be invoked without 'new'**

I have added hammerjs in app.module but there is still a problem

**This is my app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BsDropdownModule, TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';
import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';

export function tokeGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    MemberListComponent,
    ListComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    MemberCardComponent,
    MemberDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    TabsModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    NgxGalleryModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokeGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ['192.168.100.6:5000'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['192.168.100.6:5000/api/auth']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    ErrorInterceptorProvider,
    AlertifyService,
    AuthGuard,
    UserService,
    MemberDetailResolver,
    MemberListResolver
  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to display photos in each user, but it can't because of an error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can go to tsconfig.json file and change your target to es5 (ECMAScript 5)
like this :

```
  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  }
}
```

credit to : https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery/issues/242#issuecomment-483223817

or recommended way: you can use this way if you don't want change target :

going to node_modules => ngx-gallery => bundles =>  ngx-gallery.umd.js

change this :

```
var CustomHammerConfig = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
__extends(CustomHammerConfig, _super);
function CustomHammerConfig() {
    var _this = _super !== null && _super.apply(this, arguments) || this;
    _this.overrides = ({
        'pinch': { enable: false },
        'rotate': { enable: false }
    });
    return _this;
}
return CustomHammerConfig;
}(platformBrowser.HammerGestureConfig));
```

to

```
 class CustomHammerConfig extends platformBrowser.HammerGestureConfig {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.overrides = ({
            'pinch': { enable: false },
            'rotate': { enable: false }
        });
    }
}
```

https://github.com/lukasz-galka/ngx-gallery/issues/242#issuecomment-502917803

Comment: You should never modify code in node_modules directly because it may be overwritten with the next npm install. Also, if you clone the source code you will have to run npm install and thus get the broken version again ...

Answer (score 12):

There is a better approach to fixing this.

Modify the providers in your app.module.ts with

```
export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
   overrides = {
       pinch: { enable: false },
       rotate: { enable: false }
   };
}
```

and add to the Providers

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig 
    }
]
```

Comment: This is clearly the proper way of doing it. Should be the accepted answer imo.

Comment: Agreed, this should be the accepted answer. Do not downgrade to es5, and do not change your node_modules

Comment: Also, if `Class CustomHammerConfig in src/app/app.module.ts extends from a Injectable in another compilation unit without duplicating the decorator`, just put `@Injectable()` before the `exports`. Don't forget to import all needed data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I got that we can fix this by using new version of Ngx-Gallery. I just uninstalled `ngx-gallery` :

```
npm uninstall  ngx-gallery
```

Then I installed version which is supported by angular 9:

```
npm install ngx-gallery-9 --save
```

After that I just removed old references from `app.module.ts` and changed that to new format:

```
// import {NgxGalleryModule} from 'ngx-gallery'; // remove this line
import {NgxGalleryModule} from 'ngx-gallery-9';
```

Alternatively, if you are insist of using old versions, this is not good idea to change `tsconfig.ts` which others mention to it (because you want to use new features). You can easily add blow code to your `app.module.ts` and you will see changes:

```
export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig  {
   overrides = {
       pinch: { enable: false },
       rotate: { enable: false }
   };
}
```

And in the provider just add this:

```
providers: [
{ provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig }
]
```

Comment: perfect, this is the easiest solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can just open package.json and change 
**"ngx-gallery": "git://github.com/onack/ngx-gallery-dist"**
 instead of 
**"ngx-gallery": "^5.10.0"**
you'll find them in ***dependencies***

Answer (score 0):

use npm install @kolkov/ngx-gallery instead of npm install ngx-gallery and import from @kolkov/ngx-gallery in app.module.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.